# Compare distributions for equality

Tags: distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am looking for a method to compare two distributions for their equality.

E.g. assume I have a distribution of specific elements which I found theirs positions not being equally distributed (blue). If I'm now trying to identify elements according to their distribution I would like to compare their individual distribution with that accumulated distribution. So my concrete questions are:

How would I:

- normalize and
- compare

those distributions?

[image]

Comment: @Tim I think I've already found something. This is what I meant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test

Comment: Then you can post it as an answer to your question so it doesn't stay unanswered and others could also use your answer to learn something.

Comment: @Tim I will do so as soon as I'm back on my computer :)

Comment: @Stefan Falk: are you back at your computer now?